# Riesz-Markov-Kakutani representation theorem: qualitative or abstract proofs.

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, soft-question, alternative-proof, duality-theorems

I am referring to the famous result which states:

Let X be a locally compact Hausdorff space. For any positive linear functional $\psi$ on $C_c(X)$, there is a unique regular Borel measure μ on X such that
$$\psi(f)=\int_{X}fd\mu(x)\ \\ \forall f\in C_c(x)$$
The proofs I read of this result involve very tricky and seemingly articificial calculations: they are very quatitative and make a lot of use of $\epsilon-\delta$ arguments. I absolutely do not mean they are less truthful whatsoever, nonetheless I find it strange there is not a 'qualitative' proof of this result, as we have for a lot of important duality theorems.

Do anyone know some enlightening proof?

Comment: What exactly do you mean, enlightening? You are bound to have some rather heavy technical details, since the theorem implies the existence (and product properties) of the $n$-dimensional Lebesgue measure. Except that you are in a way more intricate setting, with no such nice things as orderings, dimensions, distances...

Comment: @Mindlack Let's say, a proof which encapsulates these details as much as possible, and highlights the profound meaning of the theorem...

Comment: If you don't care too much about the "regularity" part of the theorem, then the theory of the Daniell integral (see for instance https://arxiv.org/abs/1401.0310) might be interesting to you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Folland's proof (Theorem 7.2 in 1st edition *Real Analysis*) is quite conceptual, though in total the proof takes about 2.5 pages. The *idea* suggesting that this theorem should be true is very simple, though; the bulk of the proof is checking that the idea doesn't just give you a measure, but a Radon measure whose associated linear functional on $C_c(X)$ is the one you started with.

The idea is that $X$ being locally compact and Hausdorff implies (via Urysohn's lemma) that we can approximate the characteristic function of any open subset of $X$ from both above (when the closure is compact) and below (always) by continuous, compactly supported functions. This lets us define a measure for any continuous linear functional.

More precisely, for any open subset $U \subset X$, the characteristic function $\chi_U$ satisfies
$$
\chi_U(x) = \sup_{f: U \to [0, 1]} f(x),
$$
where of course I'm restricting to $f \in C_c(X)$. Then if $\psi \in C_c(X)^*$, we define the $\psi$-measure of $U$ to be
$$
\mu_\psi(U) = \sup_{f: U \to [0, 1]} \psi(f). 
$$
Since the Borel $\sigma$-algebra is generated by open subsets, this suffices to define $\mu_\psi(E)$ for any Borel set $E \subset X$ (via Caratheodory's theorem).

As mentioned in the comments, checking that this definition gives a Radon measure, and $\int \, f \, d\mu_\psi = \psi(f)$ requires some work and estimates, but nothing quite as nitty-gritty as $\varepsilon-\delta$ arguments. I think by construction $\mu_\psi$ looks promisingly like it will be inner-regular, at least. It may even look promising that in the case $\overline{U}$ is compact, we could use an $\inf$ over $f \in C_c(X)$ with $f \ge \chi_U$ above when defining $\mu_\psi(U)$ and get the same value. I'll leave it to your imagination (or to Folland's) to check $\int\,f\,d\mu_\psi = \psi(f)$.